# How To pass Optional Arguments

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have one function having two fixed arguments. But next arguments are not fixed, there can be two or three or four of them.

It's a runtime arguments so how can I define that function?

My code looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, dynamic arguments comming it should be 2 or 3)
        {

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: mayby is this something for you?:
http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) [params (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors>ErrorCollectionWithValue
                (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, params object[] args)
{
    //...
}
```

2) [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, object arg1 = null, int arg2 = int.MinValue)
{
    //...
}
```

3) And maybe simple method [overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) would still suit better, separating method logic to different methods? Under this link you can also find another description of named and optional parameters

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to have overloaded methods

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, int param1)
{
   //do some thing with param1
}

public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, int param1,int param2)
{
   //do some thing with param1 and param3
}

public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, int param1, int param2, int param3)
    {
       //do some thing with param1, param2 and param3
    }
```

then all these would be valid

```
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1);
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1,2);
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1,2,3);
```

Another approach is to use optional parameters. With this you need only one method as opposed to the 3 in the first approach.

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue
    (string ErrorDode, int MulCopyNo, int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, optional int param3 = 0)
{

}
```

these are still valid

```
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1); //defaults param2 and param3 to 0
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1,2); //defaults param3 to 0
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", 10, 1,2,3);
```

To skip any of the optional parameters, you need to use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37795/C-4-0-s-New-Features-Explained) which is only supported in C# 4.0 and above

```
var err = ErrorCollectionWithValue("text", param3: 5); //skipping param1 and param2
```

In the other two approaches, you can't skip the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28VS.71%29.aspx), if the number of argument may vary:

```
public ObservableCollection<ERCErrors> ErrorCollectionWithValue(string errorCode, int num, params object[] args) 
{ 
  foreach(object obj in args)
{
  //process args.
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's it what i want.