# How to make an anonymous method accept variable number of arguments?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates, arguments

I'd like to be able to make inline calls to anonymous methods with variable number of arguments (sometimes with no arguments, sometimes with 11).

```
Dictionary<string, Action> ActionDic = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
int i = 0;
ActionDic["something"] = () => { i += 1; };           // this line is ok
ActionDic["somethingArgs"] = (int n) => { n += 1; };  // but this is not
    // Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments
```

So I can't make a delegate accept arguments like that. Is my syntax wrong, or is it just not possible? Or do I have to change the type of anonymous method I should use for my dictionary?

Comment: OK I changed the title so it's more clear what I want.

Comment: Whatever `ActionDic` is, its string indexer accepts `Action` (or another parameterless delegate with no return type). If it would be `Action<T>`, you could do it like `p => DoStuff(p)`.

Comment: @user1306322 please, consider reading [How To pass Optional Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577730/how-to-pass-optional-arguments/12578150#12578150). Though it has nothing to do with anonymous methods, but it may give you some clue on how to pass variable number of arguments

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I'm familiar with making arguments optional, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Action<int>` if you want to define a delegate with 1 integer argument. For example:

```
Action<int> somethingArgs = (int n) => { n += 1; };
```

You haven't shown what the `ActionDic` variable is but if it is an `IDictionary<string, Action>` you cannot make this work because `Action` do not accept an argument.

What you could do on the other hand is to use a dictionary of delegates:

```
IDictionary<string, Delegate> ActionDic = ...
ActionDic["something"] = (Action)(() => { i += 1; }); 
ActionDic["somethingArgs"] = (Action<int>)((int n) => { n += 1; });
```

Comment: If I may ask, how do I also make it possible to make delegates that may return something? (non-void)

Comment: You could use `Func<TResult>`. And if you want it to take an argument you could use `Func<TArg, TResult>`. And if you want 2 arguments: `Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>`. And so on.

Comment: So I guess I can't use just one dictionary, since these would be different types of anonymous methods.

Comment: Of course that you can use a dictionary. You just need to make it an `IDictionary<string, Delegate>` as shown in my answer. `Delegate` is the base class of all delegates.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `Action` and `Action<T>` are different, incompatible delegate types.

There are several ways to compensate for this.

One would be to make `ActionDic` a `Dictionary<string, Action<int>>` but that may not satisfy all possible delegates you would want to use.

Another would be to make `ActionDic` something like a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` but this would cumbersome to use because you need to know exactly how many many parameters (and their types) to pass each function. This information would need to be stored in another data structure somewhere.

Still a third way would be to make `ActionDic` a `Dictionary<string, Action<object[]>>` and require the delegate to unpack whatever arguments it needs from the input. The caller would be responsible for knowing exactly what arguments to use. This would allow somewhat less awkward syntax of the second option, but require more code in each delegate.

Comment: I'm ready to make a separate delegate manager class for that, but still I'd like to make the declaration of each delegate a little easier to read than `ActionDic["somethingArgs"] = (Action<int>)((int n) => { /* ... */ });` because of possible great numbers of arguments.

Comment: @user1306322 I have added a third possibility which might be slightly easier to read: `ActionDic["somethingArgs"] = (object[] objs) => { int n = (int)objs[0]; /* ... */ };`

Comment: Thanks, now I see how improving readability in one part of code can kill it in the other :)

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about two different delegates, i.e. `Action` and `Action<T>`. You cannot assign `Action<T>` to `Action`:

```
Action a1 = () => { i += 1; };
Action<int> a2 = (n) => { n += 1; };
```

I suppose you're having `Dictionary<string,Action>`, so this dictionary cannot accept a value of `Action<T>`.

As a side note, I'd say that the second delegate is absolutely  useless, as it increments an `int` argument, passed by value, that is in fact doing nothing.

Also consider reading [How To pass Optional Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577730/how-to-pass-optional-arguments/12578150#12578150). Though it has nothing to do with anonymous methods, but it may give you some clue on how to pass variable number of arguments

Answer (score 0):

Action is a short way to create a delegate that returns void and take no argument.
If you want actions with argument, you need to use generic form :

`Action<int>` is a delegate that takes one int parameter

`Action<string, double>` takes 2 parameters : first is string second is double.